# MySQL query on first job date

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQL query with multiple joins on a few tables. One of these tables is a list of jobs. I want to put a `where` clause on first job date.

```
SELECT      leads.*, orders.*, jobs.* 
FROM        leads 
LEFT JOIN   orders  ON leads.lead_id = orders.lead_id 
LEFT JOIN   jobs    ON orders.order_id = jobs.order_id 
WHERE       (first_job_date) >= $date
```

Now I don't understand How to get that first_job_date from all those jobs.
I'v tried:

```
first_job_date = (
    SELECT job_date 
    FROM jobs 
    WHERE jobs.order_id = orders.order_id
    ORDER BY jobs.job_date
    LIMIT 1
)
```

But it never works, although this `SELECT` statement works when I put it inside `SELECT` query.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: actually, I'm not sure why your sub-query didn't work

Comment: @Jakumi I used the sub-query but the way you mentioned in your answered and it worked :)

Comment: "it never work" is not a useful diagnostic. It doesn't return the result your expecting? it gives an error? Why are using a LEFT JOIN when your predicate requires a specific date, aprently from one of the joined tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated after understanding the problem**

if you want all jobs from an order, whose first job_date is >= $date ...

this could work:

```
[WHERE] date > (
     SELECT MIN(temp.job_date)
     FROM jobs temp 
     WHERE temp.order_id = jobs.order_id
)
```

or alternatively ADDED as subquery in join

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT temp.order_id, MIN(temp.job_date) as job_date
    FROM jobs temp
    GROUP BY temp.order_id
) as first_job_date ON (
   temp.order_id=jobs.order_id)
```

and in your `WHERE`  you could then compare to `first_job_date.job_date`

Comment: There are multiple jobs per order

Comment: @zeus possibly misunderstood your question. updated my answer.

Comment: I don't want all the jobs but only those with min dates that is why the where clause

Comment: would you please define out of which set of jobs, you want the ones with min dates? out of the jobs assigned to the same order, the same leads, ???

Comment: the first job date is used as a filter to get all the records when compared to that first job date

Comment: `min(job_date) >= $date`

Comment: just to be sure i understand correctly ... you want all jobs, from an order, if the first job of that order has a date > a specific query date?

Comment: alright, have updated the queries in my post to reflect that problem description

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a sub query?

Will this work?

```
SELECT      leads.*, orders.*, jobs.* 
FROM        leads 
LEFT JOIN   orders  ON leads.lead_id = orders.lead_id 
LEFT JOIN   jobs    ON orders.order_id = jobs.order_id 

where MIN(jobs.job_date) >= $date
```

$date --> "YYYY-MM-DD"

Comment: But this will give the min job from the whole table, I think